# UIText Label refresh after Sub View Dismiss

Tags: swift

I have a pop over view controller to change a setting. It updates the text in the app from a `UIPickerView`. It works great, but the text label does not refresh when I dismiss the pop over view controller. The label updates when I press back and return to the view controller.

How can I refresh the current view after dismissing the pop over view controller?

Here is the code which loads the pop over:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "trustSelect") as! WelcomeViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

The pop over view controller uses the following code to dismiss the view controller when a button is tapped:

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to use local notification,

1) put this in your pop over view

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object:nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

2) Then in your ViewController paste this in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.ChangeText), name: "refresh", object: nil)
```

3) Then paste this method somewhere in ViewController,

```
func ChangeText(){
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.parent?.textLabel.text = "Random text"
 }
}
```

Comment: this is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the text in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.parent?.textLabel.text = "Random text"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would I put this? In the dismiss button or in the view controller which contains the label?

Comment: Here I thought you were setting it from the popover controller. So as it is a child view controller I used the parent property. Have updated my answer